# SQL: Using AVG() in a Greater or Lesser Then to only return those rows

Tags: sql

```
SELECT name, population
FROM countries 
WHERE population > AVG(population);
```

In case more additions are added, I cannot keep the AVG of the population as a number. This won't run as I get the error:

> misuse of aggregate function AVG()

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I suppose you must use having and group by instead of where if you want to include aggregate functions in the filter. But depeding on the database, you may use window functions, or subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can't use aggregate function in where like that.it should be used in a sub-query for your solution/
here is how you can do it,

```
SELECT name, population
FROM countries 
WHERE population > ( select AVG(population) FROM countries) ;
```

you also can populate the avg population in a variable:

```
declare @avgpop as decimal 
select @avgpop= AVG(population) FROM countries;

SELECT name, population
FROM countries 
WHERE population > @avgpop ;
```

Comment: Ha, I was just about to try this solution but didn't think it'd work. What would be the best solution for something like this?

Comment: this is the best solution  ;)